# I have some doubts regarding my if condition

Tags: c, string, if-statement, char, stdio

I'm just a noob/newbie in the C/programming world. I'll first post the code and then I'll describe my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main ()
{
  char f[30], j[30] = "mount everest";
  int s,a=0;
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?\n");
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("Please type your answer below\n");
  scanf("%[a-z]s",f);
  s = strcmp (f, j);
  printf ("\n");
 
  if (s == 0)
    {
      printf ("Congratulations! You have recieved a point!\n");
      a++;
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("Sorry! Better luck next time!");
      a--;
    }
  
  return 0;
}
```

So when I try to type the answer as "mount everest", the output goes directly to my 'else'(**Sorry! Better luck next time!**) statement. Also, I want the program to only accept small letters(*as I've defined it a strict rule to be followed throughout the quiz*).

```
**OUTPUT** 

2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?

Please type your answer below
mount everest

Sorry! Better luck next time!
```

But when I use (not)'!s' instead of 's' in my if condition, it fulfills the if condition and prints the message as '**Congratulations! You have recieved a point!**'. I really don't know what is going on? I had the same approach for my other 2 questions and they all worked perfectly without this '!' issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main ()
{
  char f[30], j[30] = "mount everest";
  int s,a=0;
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?\n");
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("Please type your answer below\n");
  scanf("%[a-z]s",f);
  s = strcmp (f, j);
  printf ("\n");
 
  if (!s == 0)
    {
      printf ("Congratulations! You have recieved a point!\n");
      a++;
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("Sorry! Better luck next time!");
      a--;
    }
  
  return 0;
}
```

```
**OUTPUT**

2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?

Please type your answer below
mount everest

Congratulations! You have recieved a point!
```

So someone can please explain this to me of what is happening(*as I'm new so I kinda don't know how to understand debugging*) and what am I doing wrong here? Also, if you cannot understand from this section of the code, I'll post the whole code here but for now I thought it would be too overwhelming so if u want then pleasedo let me know! Thank you for taking the time to go through  my problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I programmed the code again with the help of such useful comment from you guys/contributers(*thank u all for taking the time to help this newbie*) now I'll show you the revised/new code first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main ()
{
  char f[30], j[30] = "mount everest";
  int s,a=0;
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?\n");
  printf ("\n");
  printf ("Please type your answer below\n");
  fgets(f,15,stdin);
  printf("%s\n",f);
  printf("%s\n",j);
  printf ("\n");
  s=strcmp(f,j);
  if (s==0)
    {
      printf ("Congratulations! You have recieved a point!\n");
      a++;
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("Sorry! Better luck next time!");
      a--;
    }
    
  
  return 0;
}
```

But now I'm again being thrown back at the else condition. Like this:

```
Output

2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?

Please type your answer below
mount everest
mount everest

mount everest

Sorry! Better luck next time!
```

I know there is an issue with the 'if' condition but can't seem to figure out what it is. So if anyone can detect my error then I would be really glad. Once again thank you all for helping me.

Comment: strcmp return 0 if string matches, you wrote your condition is `!s == 0` <- this is incorrect. condition should be `s==0`

Comment: Debugging tip: use `printf("[%s]\n", f)` to see what was stored in `f`.

Comment: `%[a-z]` only reads letters; there's a space between `mount` and `everest`.  One possible fix is to add a space to the character set.  Note, too, the `%[…]` is a scan-set and is complete; it is not a modifier for `%s` so the `s` in `%[a-z]s` is not wanted.  In general, it causes problems, though you won't notice them here.

Comment: I'll use the printf("[%s]\n", f) and will let you know. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3386109 
I used the printf("[%s]\n",f); and it gave me the ouput as [mount]. Dunno why?

Comment: The `"%[a-z]"` conversion will stop when it finds any character that isn't a lower case letter. Which means it stops when it finds the space character after `mount`. You could try adding the space character to the set of allowed characters, e.g. `"%[a-z ]"`. Personally, I would use `fgets` to read the whole line ([but you'll have to remove the newline that `fgets` puts in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776)).

Comment: Get rid of scanf and use fgets.

Comment: @user3386109
I used the fgets function and now it is printing the and that I needed but...it is still telling me that the ans is wrong as it is going in the else statement. This the new modified code:

https://onlinegdb.com/CUCY4jyKjJ


``But the output is this:

2) Which is the tallest mountain in the world?

Please type your answer below
mount everest
mount everest

mount everest

Sorry! Better luck next time!
``
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @BlackApathy Keep in mind that fgets doesn't discard the \n so you have to do that manually. Here's the FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: I thnk Lundin is correct that the newline wasn't removed. That's the reason for the square brackets in `printf("[%s]\n", f);` The brackets let you see if there's a newline in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your program is not working is because your scanf is not taking the whole line as input. Instead, it is taking the first word.
Try to use  `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",f);`

In future when your code is not working, try to print and verify the input you're receiving and validate from it.

Comment: Printing what you got as input to verify that the computer got what you thought it got is a very basic, but very important, debugging technique.

Comment: I tried using the ```scanf("%[^\n]%*c",f)``` but it only ended up in printing the "everest" and discarding "mount".

Comment: Or just view the input in your favourite debugger. No need to print anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%[a-z]s",f);
```

should be

```
scanf("%[a-z ]",f);
```

`%[a-z]` means look for a nonempty sequence of lower case characters. You forgot to tell it to look for space.

Also `%[a-z]s` means look for a nonempty sequence of lower case characters followed by an 's'.